# Tensorflow privacy library is not downloaded

Tags: tensorflow, github

I try to install Tensorflow Privacy but I could not even TensorFlow privacy installed every time but Whenever I try to install Tensorflow privacy library then they giving me an error Which I already attached in an image? How I can solve this error?
[Tensorflow Privacy library error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlR2e.jpg)

Actually, I try to run a code for my understanding but because of TenserFlow library issue I can, t run it?

Comment: Hi @Syed Ali You are facing an error related to Python package installation. Ensure that you're using the latest versions of pip and setuptools, which are essential for package installation and metadata generation. You can update pip using pip install --upgrade pip and setuptools using pip install --upgrade setuptools. Issues can arise due to a corrupted pip cache. You can try clearing the pip cache using pip cache purge.